# Designing a regex to exclude parts of a string with a backslash

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to clean-up a column of strings from a csv file that has extra characters. I'm trying to use the following regex: `(r'([A-Za-z0-9\s]+)')` on strings such as `'Robert Johnson\xa0'` to extract just `'Robert Johnson'`, but the resulting string is unchanged. Not sure how to modify the regex so that `'\xa0'` is not included in the final string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all you need to extract in string excludes numbers. then this should work

```
(r'([A-Za-z]+)\b')
```

Comment: It gives the full string including the hex values

Comment: you might need to be clearer on what output you need. the regex outputs just Robert Johnson

Comment: what regex method are you using like findall(), search()?

Comment: I am using pd.str.extract(). The suggested regex worked in the context that I needed. Thanks, Ade_1!

Answer (score 0):

Try this `(r'(^[A-Za-z\s]+))` this gives

**Robert Johnson**

**Any Name**

Match details

```
[
  [
    {
      "content": "Robert Johnson",
      "isParticipating": true,
      "groupNum": 0,
      "groupName": null,
      "startPos": 0,
      "endPos": 14
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "content": "Any Name",
      "isParticipating": true,
      "groupNum": 0,
      "groupName": null,
      "startPos": 19,
      "endPos": 27
    }
  ]
]
```